# No such file or directory but file present

Tags: c++, c, linux, netbeans

I am trying to build libnetfilter_queue by myself. I successfully build libmnl and libnfnetlink. But when I trying to build libnetfilter_queue, I've got and an error:

```
libnetfilter_queue.c:33:39: fatal error: libnfnetlink/libnfnetlink.h: No such file or directory
```

All the pathes are setted. I tried to set them both by -I flag and in NetBeans project settings (as relative path, as absolute path etc) but it still doesn't work. I also installed build-essential but still the same problem. chmod tells me, that file is readable for all users. And also interesting thing is when I try to do "Navigate->Go to declaration/Definition", it opens that file. What is the problem?

Comment: Suggest posting the makefile and layout of your directories and what directory your building from.  Until we have the background info, all we can do is guess as to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you are building different libraries right?

if so, if you are building using make file, first create a library file(.a) file of libnfnetlink and while building libnetfilter_queue, in the c flag add the library -I

Comment: Yes. libnetfilter_queue depends from other 2. They build before main library so that is not a problem. And -l flag is needed while linkage and I have error in compilation stage. But thank's